# How do you save a webpage as html code?

Tags: html

I am trying to save a webpage and translate it to html code. Is this possible to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Web pages are already HTML, by definition.

Comment: Depending on what browser you use there's usually a option somewhere that says `view source`

Comment: Do you mean programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your browser, do  Ctrl/Cmd-s

OR

View the page source (right-click, save as), copy all of it and save.

There is no translation to be done. Rendered web pages are always HTML, though they may also contain JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I know my question was vague, but your response was helpful.